# hide and show buttons not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for uploading an image: (it's from a template that uses bootstrap 2)

```
 <div class="span6">
   <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label">Imagen</label>
       <div class="controls">
         <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
           <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail hide" id="upload" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
             <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="Beneficio"/>
           </div>
           <div class="hide fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;" id="preview"></div>
             <div id="imagen">
               <span class="btn btn-file">
                 <span class="fileupload-new hide" id="select_button">Seleccione</span>
                 <span class="fileupload-exists hide" id="change_button">Cambiar</span>
                 <input type="file" class="default" name="file"/>
               </span>
               <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists hide" data-dismiss="fileupload" id="removebutton">Remover</a>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

I'm using "hide" on some elements because I need to hide those buttons in case javascript on client browser is not active, because it looks all messy and buttons change_button and remove_button should only appear after uploading the image. And select_button in that case should be hidden again.

So when comes to do the js code, I did this:

```
$('#upload').show('hide');
$('#select_button').removeClass('hide');
$('#preview').show();

$('#select_button').click(function(){
  $('#select_button').addClass('hide');
  $('#change_button').show();
  $('#remove_button').show();
});
```

select_button is being hide ok, but change_button and remove_button does not appear after I use the show function.

When inspecting the code, no errors appears. So what I am doing wrong? why those buttons does not appear?

Comment: Where did you come up with `.show('hide');` ??

Comment: @TJ because I was trying with "removeClass('hide')" and then when used show() forgot to erase 'hide'

Comment: @cVplZ sorry, I won't accept any answers bc none is correct and I still can't solve this

Answer (score 2):

The bootstrap `hide` class contains `display:none !important` which overrides the inline `display` value added by the script.

For displaying the element, remove the class `hide` using [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) method as follows:

```
$('#upload').removeClass('hide');
$('#select_button').removeClass('hide');
$('#preview').removeClass('hide');
$('#select_button').click(function(){
  $('#select_button').addClass('hide');
  $('#change_button').removeClass('hide');
  $('#remove_button').removeClass('hide');
});
```

*Update:*

Other than that, you are using the wrong selectors, in `HTML` you've  id `removebutton`, and in script you're using `#remove_button`. Make sure all of your selectos are correct.

Comment: This is the correct answer. As a side note, to make the jQuery easier, you could do `$('.hide').removeClass('.hide').hide();` right after page load, and then `$.show()` and `$.hide()` will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have also  tried with removeClass just as you suggested, but it's not working

Comment: @TJ Tryied changing the names, and still nothing. I put an alert inside the function, and that It's not showing either. Maybe it has to be with the selector?

Answer (score 0):

`.show('hide')` is not valid [reference](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

use `.hide()` instead [reference](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: FYI, `.show('hide')` [does work](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsmuujrq/), jquery just ignores the invalid argument...

Answer (score 0):

jquery does not use `.show('hide')` read about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp). Instead use `.show()` and `.hide()`

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I got confused...when removing 'hide' doesn't work either

Comment: I would strongly suggest to read [this w3schools link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)

Comment: I will humbly request not to follow that link... and @starvator please stop sharing links to w3schools. they contains lots of outdated info. If you want to provide links to jquery methods you can better link to the official [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com)

Comment: FYI, `.show('hide')` [does work](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsmuujrq/), jquery just ignores the invalid argument...